# adding two validators to Parsley.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsley.js

What i basically want to do is have check values that user entered in an input field against two separate arrays. One is an Array of words that would create an error , other is an Array of words that would raise a warning.
I have created these 2 functions and they seem to work fine when they are bound with two different fields

```
 , warning: function () {
      var that = this;
      return {
            validate: function (val,arrayRange) {
                    var warningWords = new Array();
                    warningWords[0]="Cricket";
                    warningWords[1]="Football";
                for (var i = 0; i < warningWords.length; i++) {
                        if(val.toLowerCase()===warningWords[i].toLowerCase())
                            return false;
                }
                return true;
        }
        , priority: 32
      }
    }
  , wrong: function () {
      var that = this;
      return {
            validate: function (val,arrayRange) {
                    var errorWords = new Array();
                    errorWords[0]="Justin";
                    errorWords[1]="Chester";
                for (var i = 0; i < errorWords.length; i++) {
                        if(val.toLowerCase()===errorWords[i].toLowerCase())
                            return false;
                }
                return true;
        }
        , priority: 32
      }
    }
```

and the HTML

```
  <label for="email">ERROR :</label>
<input name="message1" id="error" parsley-trigger="keyup" parsley-wrong="" ></input>

<label for="message">Warning</label>
<input name="message" parsley-trigger="keyup" parsley-warning=""></input>
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
```

Is it possible to bind both of these functions to the same input field?
And secondly i want that in case of warning the input fields background would turn yellow and in case of wrong it should turn red
I have over ridden the parsley-error class . But can i create another class that would be triggered when warning function invalidates the form.

Thirdly is it possible to submit the form even if warning functions causes the field to be invalidated?
It is easy to achieve through JS , so can we some how block parsley from stopping the form validation.

Answer (score 0):

For Q1, you should be able to have multiple custom validators on the same input, just like you can use more than one of parsley's built-in validators. Raise or lower the priorities if you want to force one to validate first.

In response to Q2, you could add additional classes to the input to modify the parsley-error styling. Here's an example:

```
input.parsley-error {
    background-color: #f00;
}

input.parsley-error.warning {
    background-color: #ff0;
}
```

So if you were to have both validators on the same input field you could have the warning validator add a .warning class when it returns false and remove that class when returning true.

For Q3, you should be able to submit the form despite validation issues by overriding the 'onFormValidate' listener and have it return true, even if the 'isFormValid' parameter is false.

```
$('#formId').parsley({
    listeners: {
        onFormValidate: function(isFormValid, event, ParsleyForm) {
            return true;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: You can have more than one of parsley's built-in validators active on a single field?  I haven't been able to find an example of this.  Do you have an example?